# How to return an image created with php

Tags: php, image, file

I want to return an image when a PHP script is called.

The problem I am having is, that I have the image saved in a variable (`$image`).

I know I could first save the image on the server with

```
imagepng($image, 'image.png');
```

and after that return it with something like

```
readfile('image.png');
```

but I am sure there is a more elegant way to do the job, I just don't know it.
Is there a way to combine these two commands or any other way, that allows me not to use a temporary file?

Comment: If you want to get the image data, you could output the image (to the browser by not specifying a filename) with output buffering to catch the data, which will give you the contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imagepng($image)`, with no second parameter, will simply dump the raw PNG data out to the client (e.g. the browser). No need to write it to a file, then read that file back in.

This is clearly documented in the man page: http://php.net/imagepng and applies to ALL of the "save" functions in GD.